# Combine cells matching data into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any VBA code or complicated excel function that would assist with what I need done? I export thousands of ref#s with check#s that need to be combined into one cell with the correspond check #. I know I can combine text, and I could probably use a VLUP function with it, but I'm not sure of the exact function string that should be used.

Basically, rows A2:A4 all share the check# 999, so when I run the script or input the function, it should combine in row C2 the ref#s 1 2 3. In the next chk# row it would combine reference#s 4 5, so on and so on (example is in the table below). All separated with spaces. Is this possible? It is very tedious to do it all by hand.
Example...

```
Ref #   Chk #   Combined #
1       999     1 2 3
2       999
3       999
4       1000    4 5
5       1000
6       1001    6
7       1002    7
8       1003    8
9       1004    9 10 11 12
10      1004
11      1004
12      1004
13      1005    13 14
14      1005
```

Comment: What Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a formula answer without the need for vba.

Use a helper column.  So in C2 put:

```
=IF(B2<>B3,A2,A2 & " " & C3)
```

Then in D2 put:

```
=IF(B2<>B1,C2,"")
```

And copy both down.

[image]

Then you can hide C.

Comment: Very clever way to use the downwards reference *(+1)*